# Mongo Query to get a result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongo collection name tests and whose having the following documents in it.

```
[
  {
    "title": "One",
    "uid": "1",
    "_metadata": {
      "references": [
        {
          "uid": "2"
        },
        {
          "asssetuid": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Two",
    "uid": "2",
    "_metadata": {
      "references": [
        {
          "uid": "3"
        },
        {
          "asssetuid": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Three",
    "uid": "3",
    "_metadata": {
      "references": []
    }
  }
]
```

And I want the result in the following format (for uid:1)

```
[
  {
    "title": "One",
    "uid": 1,
    "_metadata": {
      "references": [
        {
          "asssetuid": 10
        },
        {
          "asssetuid": 11
        },
        {
          "title": "Two",
          "uid": "2",
          "_metadata": {
            "references": [
              {
                "title": "Three",
                "uid": "3"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

for uid:2 I want the following result

```
[
  {
    "title": "Two",
    "uid": 2,
    "_metadata": {
      "references": [
        {
          "asssetuid": 11
        },
        {
          "title": "Three",
          "uid": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Which query I used here to get a respected result. according to its uid. here I want the result in the parent-child relationship. is this possible using MongoDB graph lookup query or any other query that we can use to get the result. Please help me with this.

New Type Output

```
[{
"title": "One",
"uid": 1,
"_metadata": {
    "assets": [{
        "asssetuid": 10,
        "parent": 1
    }, {
        "asssetuid": 11,
        "parent": 2
    }],
    "entries": [{
        "title": "Two",
        "uid": "2",
        "parent": 1
    }, {
        "title": "Three",
        "uid": "3",
        "parent": 2
    }]
}
```

}]

Comment: Okay... @SurajDalvi so you strictly want to resolve the references in nested form or the flat map will also do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo supports the automatic reference resolution using `$ref` but for that, you need to change your schema a little and resolve resolution is only supported by some drivers.

You need to store your data in this format:

```
[
  ...
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "_metadata": {
      "references": [
        {
          "$ref": "collection",
          "$id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
          "$db": "database"
        },
        {
          "asssetuid": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "One",
    "uid": "1"
  },
  ....
]
```

For more details on `$ref` refer to official documentation: [label-document-references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#std-label-document-references)

OR

you can resolve the reference using the `$graphLookup` but the only problem with the `$graphlookup` is that you will lose the `assetuid`. Here is the query and it will resolve references and give output in flat map

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      uid: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$_metadata.references.uid",
      connectFromField: "_metadata.references.uid",
      connectToField: "uid",
      depthField: "depth",
      as: "resolved"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "references": "$resolved",
      "metadata": [
        {
          "_metadata": "$_metadata"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "references._metadata": 0,
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "references": "$references",
      "merged": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$metadata",
          "$resolved"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      results: [
        {
          merged: "$merged"
        },
        {
          references: "$references"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$results"
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "assest": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "results.merged": {
              "$exists": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$results.merged"
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$results.merged._metadata.references"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "results.merged._metadata.references.asssetuid": {
              "$exists": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            _id: 0,
            "asssetuid": "$results.merged._metadata.references.asssetuid"
          }
        }
      ],
      "uid": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "results.references": {
              "$exists": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$results.references"
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$results.references"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "references": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$assest",
          "$uid"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the link to the playground to test it: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vPPt1xUYRR4)

Comment: thanks but I can't able to change my schema. is any way to get the result using the given schema. and all these are part of schema collection

Comment: is any way to show assetuid in graph lookup? I need that too and is any way to show a nested view of the result instead of flat and if the nested view is not possible  then can to show depth means depth 1, depth2 etc

Comment: Yes, @SurajDalvi I have added the depth field which can show the nesting. I am working on to get the `assetuid` also

Comment: Hi @SurajDalvi, I have updated the query and playground... this will resolve the references as well as preserve the `assetuid`

Comment: just one query here instead of Depth can we show parent uid in the result?

Comment: Yes.. @SurajDalvi just update the expected output in your question I will try to get that output

Comment: how we can get duplicate value in Graphlookup with various depth

Comment: please check New Type Output in question need  new format result please help me

Comment: Hi @SurajDalvi, please post a question as now there is a complete change in the expected output

Comment: hi @HandsomeCoder I have created a new question for this can you please check the following link and help me there:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892303/mongo-grpahlookup-query-to-get-a-result